# Usage of ‘to’ in English

Tags: verbs, infinitives

I know when to is preposition, we can use any word except verb after ‘to’

for example: *going to school* → here ‘to’ is a preposition.

When acts as ‘to infinitive’ there will be always verb1 form after ‘to’.

Is there any chance of having any other verb forms like ‘verb2’ or ‘verb3’ after ‘to’ in any situation either past or presented or future or any?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what verb2 and verb3 are, but the only other form of a verb I can think of that can follow "to" is the present participle when it is used as a simple noun or gerund. When "to" is not an infinitive marker, it is a preposition, and prepositions require nouns to be their direct objects. So, here is an example of "to" with a present participle used as a gerund:

> We are accustomed to giving it our all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what verb form this would be because I'm a native speaker and didn't learn verbs that way, but you can say things like:

If some guy got a 100% on a really hard exam and he claims he didn't study but you think he must have: "He has/had to have studied." (Has or had both sound fine here, but if I was talking about something long ago, I would use "had.")

Comment: Your example is still an infinitive form. The verb _before_ "to" doesn't matter for this question. Only "have" can actually follow "to" here, which I believe must be the verb1 form.

Comment: Oh, I thought that "have studied" was perhaps a different tense.

Comment: I think I see what you are saying! The past participle (studied) _after_ the infinitive _is_ interesting. But the word immediately following "to" still always has to be the base form of "have."